# How to specify unicode characters in patterns for fslex

Tags: regex, unicode, f#, fslex

What is the correct way to specify Unicode characters in pattern for FSharp Lexer. 
Following code is not compiled with the FsLex.exe utility:

```
let lexeme lexbuf = LexBuffer<char>.LexemeString lexbuf
...
rule tokenize = parse   

| ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z'] { TOKEN1 }  
| [\u0100\u0101]    { TOKEN2 } 
| [\u0102-\u01FF]   { TOKEN3 }  
...
| [eof]             { EOF }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S: I'm using fslex.exe with --unicode option

Thanks, Vitaliy

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can try looking at the F# `lex.fsl` file here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/lex.fsl

Comment: Nice example to work with. I found mistake - absent quotes - solution would be use following construction ['\u0100'-'\u01FF'].

Comment: @Tomas: Another observation - if I specify too wide range ['\u0100'-'\uFFFF'], compilation takes more time and compiled lexer.fs file will be comparable big (tens of MB). So possible better in some cases use specific characters: '\Ll', '\Lu', etc. - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#Y11856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to put the unicode characters in single quotes, just like in normal F# code.

At least that seems to work for a small example that I tested.